# Devise + Facebook omniauth: The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

I found similar threads on SO, but none of them helped me to solve this issue.
My routes looks like:

```
devise_for :users do
    post '/users' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'user_registration'
end
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
```

I’ve also tried:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

But I am still getting

```
The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

I’ve even tried to restart server, but it didn’t help me. I am following [this tutorial](http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/articles/2012/01/20/adding-facebook-auth-to-rails-3-1-app/).

`omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
            puts @user.inspect
            flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: have you created app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb file also the facebook method there?

Comment: yes, I added it to the OP.

Comment: how you solved finally, i think that i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your devise route to

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

to make sure it matches your controller definition.

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes. Maybe they generate twice. Try:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
devise_scope :users do
  post '/users' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'user_registration'
end
```